# What are the formats of date string outputs from Date class functions?

Tags: javascript, date

There are a ton of different functions which return formatted strings from Date, and I can never remember what they look like.  What do they all look like?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

EDIT: This is a Q&A.  I added the answer with the question, which is why the question is so lame.  I've gotten tired of having to do this by hand all the time, so I put it here where it can be searched for and found again.

Comment: If you want this as a community question and answer, you should frame the question as something that meets [SO's requirements for topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). E.g. you might reframe the question as "*How to show a user the default ECMAScript timestamps available?*", as your answer neatly shows the methods available for the current implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 2020, these are all the different formats a date can output through its various functions:

```
Raw Date "2020-05-12T23:50:21.817Z"
toString()          -> Tue May 12 2020 18:50:21 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
toDateString()      -> Tue May 12 2020
toTimeString()      -> 18:50:21 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
toISOString()       -> 2020-05-12T23:50:21.817Z
toUTCString()       -> Tue, 12 May 2020 23:50:21 GMT
toGMTString()       -> Tue, 12 May 2020 23:50:21 GMT
toJSON()            -> 2020-05-12T23:50:21.817Z
toLocaleString()            -> 5/12/2020, 6:50:21 PM
toLocaleDateString()        -> 5/12/2020
toLocaleTimeString()        -> 6:50:21 PM
```

```js
const now = new Date();
let fns = Array.from(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype));
fns = fns.filter((key) => /^to/.test(key));

console.log("Raw Date", now);
fns.forEach((fnName) => console.log(`${fnName}() \t\t-> ${now[fnName]()}`));
```